# AWS metadata: what is the aws instance id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

Does the AWS instance id correspond do the hardware used for an instance? Is there a way to tell if your getting the same hardware in a region?

Comment: @ThomasDickey has posted an excellent answer to this question.  Clearly, "no," the instance ID tells nothing about the hardware, but also, it'a not clear why you ask about "the same" hardware (meaning "identical" or just "equivalent") -- either way, if you stop and start an instance, or terminate one and launch another, you're essentially guaranteed that the hardware will *not* be the same.  Only on stop/start will the instance ID stay the same, and that fact has no meaning with regard to the hardware. Conversely, a running instance never changes hardware, including across an instance reboot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not directly identify the hardware. These links discuss the id:

- *[Anatomy of an Amazon EC2 Resource ID](http://www.jackofallclouds.com/2009/09/anatomy-of-an-amazon-ec2-resource-id/)* goes into a lot of detail, which can be summarized as a "multi-part counter".
- *[Is the Amazon EC2 instance id unique forever?](https://serverfault.com/questions/58401/is-the-amazon-ec2-instance-id-unique-forever)* quotes Amazon to the effect that the identifier is "unique".
- *[Re: Are Instance IDs unique to region or globally at any given time?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=319825)*  again says they are unique.

Since they are unique (you will not get the same one twice), they cannot match up against particular hardware (unless you assume that Amazon has more hardware than possible id's).